# Homology of $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

I want to calculate all the homology groups of $\mathbb{R}P^\infty = \bigcup\limits_{i=o}^\infty \mathbb{R}P^n$. The tools I have are Mayer-Vietoris sequence, cofibre long exact sequences (though I don't know a cofibration involving this space), and cellular homology.

First, I'm wondering how to interpret this union. Does it involve disjoint copies of the real projective plane in each dimension? Is it like a wedge sum at the basepoint? In particular, is $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ path connected?

Second, I'm trying to calculate homology using the cellular chain complex. However, since $\mathbb{R}P^n$ has one cell in every dimension, wouldn't $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ have infinitely many cells in every dimension? Is it still true that every other map $C_i(\mathbb{R}P^\infty)\rightarrow C_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}P^\infty)$ is the zero map or multiplication by two (like in cellular homology calculations of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ for finite $n$)? Why or why not?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ has one cell in every dimension. Also yes the gluing maps are either zero or $2$. This is actually by definition. Having one cell in each dimension does not uniquely characterize $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ (consider the a wedge of spheres of each dimension), but we *define* $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ to be one cell in each dimension with these gluing maps. This should be enough information to answer the question!

Comment: @OsamaGhani each $\mathbb{R}P^n$ has one cell of every dimension so how is it that the union of infinitely many $\mathbb{R}P^n$ has only one cell of every dimension? Why wouldn't it have infinitely many cells of each dimension? I guess I'm struggling to see how this definition of $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ as a union is equivalent to your definition.

Comment: It's the union, not disjoint union. You have inclusions $\mathbb{R}P^n \to \mathbb{R}P^{n+1}$ by including into the equator, so all cells of the same dimension get identified. If you're familiar with direct limits, then this is the direct limit of $ \mathbb{R}P^0 \subset \mathbb{R}P^1 \subset \mathbb{R}P^2 ... $ although you do not need to know this because the idea is just union.

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to consider the cell decomposition of $S^n$ as two cells in each dimension (see if you can see why). Then modding by antipodal action gives $\mathbb{R}P^n$ and gives exactly one cell in each dimension. The same thing works for $S^\infty$ and $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$.

Comment: @OsamaGhani: You've given a good answer, but, rather than answering in the comments, you answer it in the answer box.

Comment: @LeeMosher I usually only comment if I feel that the question is like a misconception or doesn't involve too much work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The union is not a wedge, but a sequence of spaces $\mathbb{RP}^1\subset \mathbb{RP}^2\subset \dots$ where each space is a CW subcomplex of the next. In particular, $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is the $n$-skeleton of $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$.

It seems like you already understand the cellular chain complexes of each $\mathbb{RP}^n$, and the cellular chain complex of $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ can be inferred from them: for each $n$ the inclusion $\mathbb{RP}^n \hookrightarrow \mathbb{RP}^\infty$ induces isomorphisms $C_k(\mathbb{RP}^n) \cong C_k(\mathbb{RP}^\infty)$ for each $k \leq n$, and the boundary operators $\partial_k\colon C_k(\mathbb{RP}^\infty)\to C_{k-1}(\mathbb{RP}^\infty)$ for $k\leq n$ agree with those of $\mathbb{RP}^n$ by naturality.

In general if $X$ is a CW complex and $X^{(n)}$ is its $n$-skeleton, then the inclusion $X^{(n)}\hookrightarrow X$ induces isomorphisms $H_k(X^{(n)}) \cong H_k(X)$ for all $k<n$ (exercise: prove this). In particular, if you want to know $H_k(\mathbb{RP}^\infty)$ you could choose an $n>k$ and compute $H_k(\mathbb{RP}^n)$.